# My hard disk suddenly full

Tags: mount, disk-usage

I am a Ubuntu beginner and I started to use Ubuntu 12.10 beta 2 last week.
I found that my hard disk is full. It seems the disk does not mounted correctly. However, I have tried a lot of codes but they don't work at all.
Thanks for your help.

```
 peng@peng-ThinkPad-SL410:~$ df
文件系统           1K-块      已用    可用     已用%  挂载点
/dev/sda1      238304896 230078604 5805240   98%   /
udev             1022532         4 1022528    1%   /dev
tmpfs             412108       884  411224    1%   /run
none                5120         8    5112    1%   /run/lock
none             1030264      1152 1029112    1%   /run/shm
none              102400        36  102364    1%   /run/user
```

Translation:

文件系统 = File system

1K-块 = 1-K Blocks

已用 = Has been used

可用 = Available

已用% = Use %

挂载点 = Mount point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several tools that can display your disk usage graphically, for example [filelight](http://methylblue.com/filelight/). Without futher investigation, it is nearly impossible to say what causes your disk to get full. If you get that additional info, you should post that in your question to get more precise answers.

For me, the downloaded packages (.deb files) are often a source of high disk usage and you can clear that using the command `apt-get clean`.

And like the other answers state, I can't see why your disk shouldn't be mounted correctly.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem and it turned out a log file was getting massive.

Change to your Home directory:

```
cd /home/*yourusername*

ls -al
```

check to see if anything is way too big. 
My .xsession-errors file was 430GB!

So I deleted the darn thing:

```
sudo rm .xsession-errors
```

Comment: I found that my .xsession-errors file was about 120GB - after rm ~/.xsession-errors df shows that / is still full - what should I do - just reboot?  I'm kind of afraid to - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have a few questions first. What makes you think that the disk is not mounted correctly? Is your hard disk's 240 gb or is it very different?

Assuming its a file or bunch of files which might have caused this, you can try `du -sh /` in terminal to see which folders are abnormally large and then run the command on that folder and so on to track down the offending files if any

Answer (score 0):

You can investigate the problem with the Disk Usage Analyzer. It wil show a graphical representation of the size of files and directories on your hard drive and you can quickly drill down to the problem areas.

I see no indication that your partition is mounted incorrectly, unless you have more partitions on your hard drive that should have been mounted as well. The following command gives a list of partitions, which may help us to identify the problem:

```
sudo parted /dev/sda print
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @user121884, it may be because of your `.xsession-errors` file or `.xsession-errors-old` file (mine was around 110GB!),
which you have to remove from your system either through terminal `sudo rm .xsession-errors`  or through your file explorer and then Trash. The method worked for my linux-mint 20.04.

One other possible reason may be some backup service going on in background, like timeshift, which sometime bloats up the system memory. If this is the case, try to login through TTY and delete some unimportant big file. This will give you time to login into system, close timeshift backups and then safely delete any large and unwanted timeshift backups.

If you don't have anything critical to backup, turn off timeshift. Or you can use MEGA or Dropbox to sync your important folder to cloud.